# React router - dynamic routes - accessing state object via the router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

TLDR:
I'm making a simple 2 page app, that accesses the state object from both pages and wondering how to structure my react router (and its too late to move onto redux at this stage :P).

[Codepen is here](http://codepen.io/ashconnolly/pen/1b40a412477289047954440ef3ed2242?editors=1010), but note routing doesn’t work in codepen.

There is a list page, and a click through page with more details.
The details page (HolidayPage) is linked to using an object property from the state object using push browserHistory -
`<Route path="/:HolidayId" component={HolidayPage}/>`
I’m confused how to access the state object from this `HolidayPage` component as it isn't a child of the root app (and thus not adjacent to the state object), can i pass this route the state object as a property?

In the `HolidayPage` component I'm wanting to access the state object to output the holiday details for that specific page, eg the route `/holiday_2` would show the object data from - `state.holidays.holiday_2.details`.

Or if i used nested roots and inserted my component into the root component using {this.props.children} ([as seen here](http://codepen.io/bradwestfall/pen/reaWYL?editors=1010)) , I’m then confused how to pass state object properties to the inserted component.

my app has a state object of

```
holidays: {
            holiday_1 : {
                name : 'France',
                details : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            },
            holiday_2 : {
                name : 'Italy',
                details : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            },
            holiday_3 : {
                name : 'Spain',
                details : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            },
        }
```

routing setup like so -

```
ReactDOM.render((
 <Router history={browserHistory} >
    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout} />
    <Route path="/:HolidayId" component={HolidayPage}/>     
</Router>   
), document.getElementById('main'))
```

And to direct to the dynamic pages I'm using this code -

```
    gotoHoliday : function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();             
    var HolidayId = this.props.index;     
    browserHistory.push(HolidayId);           
},
```

On the holiday page I can show the holiday id using `{this.props.params.HolidayId}` but I'm unsure how to display the details of this `HolidayId` object.

If anyone can help me, I'd really appreciate it! :)

Comment: If someone has answered your question, click the check mark next to the answer to mark it correct. If not, update the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

So first, since your state is shared between routes you need to keep that state somewhere in the React tree above the router. Remember, data can only be passed down. Something like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    // return your holdays object
  },

  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}/>
        <Route path="/:HolidayId" component={HolidayPage}/>     
      </Router>
    )
}
```

Then you can had the holidays information as props to the routes

```
render() {
  return(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={MainLayout} holidays={this.state.holidays} />
      <Route path="/:HolidayId" component={HolidayPage} holidays={this.state.holidays}/>     
    </Router>
  )
}
```

ReactRouter makes the route props available to the route handlers. So now you can assess the state from both `MainLayout` and `HolidayPage` via `this.props.route.holidays`. You'll have to write a helper in your HolidayPage component to fetch the appropriate holiday given the holidayId. Something like:

```
this.props.route.holidays['holiday_' + this.props.params.HolidayId]
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `<HolidayPage />` access to the state object, and just look it up by id.

```
var holidays = require ('./holidays.js');

class HolidayPage... {
    render() {
        return <div>
            { holidays[ this.props.params.HolidayId} ].name }
         </div>;
    }
}
```